# The update method in hibernate does not replace the old data but create a new one?

Tags: java, hibernate

Here are my simple code, save some code in XML file.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop the existing tables and create new one -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <!-- Mention here all the model classes along with their package name -->

    <mapping class="com.hibernate.Student"/>

</session-factory>
```

Here is my student class,

```
package com.hibernate;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name="STUDENT")
public class Student {

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int rollNo;

@Column(name="FULL_NAME",nullable=false)
private String name;

public int getRollNo() {
    return rollNo;
}
public void setRollNo(int rollNo) {
    this.rollNo = rollNo;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

And the main:

```
package com.hibernate;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Student student= new Student();
        student.setName("Chang");
        SessionFactory sessionFactory=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        //session.save(student);

        //get a student from the databse
        student=(Student)session.get(Student.class, 1);
        System.out.println("Student Object have student name as:"+student.getName());

        student.setName("Chang_update");
        session.update(student);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        //sessionFactory.close();       
    }
}
```

At first, I want to create a new table and insert a new student. So I let the `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>`. And I have a `session.save(student);` I do not have these part of code:

```
student=(Student)session.get(Student.class, 1);
System.out.println("Student Object have student name as:"+student.getName());

student.setName("Chang_update");
session.update(student);
```

Then I want to test the get and update method. So I changed the `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>` , delete `session.save(student);` and add

```
student=(Student)session.get(Student.class, 1);
System.out.println("Student Object have student name as:"+student.getName());

student.setName("Chang_update");
session.update(student);
```

Then I run the code. The get method works good with a return Chang. But for the update method, i thought it will replace the old data. But it came out with a new student called Chang_update with a RollNo of 1. The old Chang's RollNo became 2.

I am new to hibernate, can you guys give me a hint what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think that this is the issue, but you should have a @Version column identified so that Hibernate can do its concurrency management correctly.

The @Id with the GenerationType.AUTO is letting Hibernate manage the PK.  Because the id field is an int (primitive) vs. Integer (which can have null), there's always a value in there, even its zero.  Therefore, don't think it's possible for hibernate to tell whether this is a new row or not, and needs to create a new one each time and, for whatever reason, knows that there's already a PK of 1 and updates the other?

Not completely familiar with AUTO but I'd suggest changing the id field to an Integer and perhaps use sequence object generation.

Comment: All `AUTO` influences is how Hibernate will manage the PK value.  This means some databases may be based upon a sequence, others an identity/auto_increment column, etc.  `AUTO` tells Hibernate to let the database dictate the method of choice rather than it being a specific approach across all database vendors.  Your problem is as @ScottSosna said, your PK values should be object types and not primitives.